# How Can I Read Draft mails using Python?

Tags: python, email, imaplib

```
import imaplib

username = 'me@example.com'
password = 'password'
mail_server = 'mail.example.com'
imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=mail_server)
imap_server.login(username, password)
```

i don't know what do after this. help me to read my draft mails using python.

Comment: It might not be possible with imap. The server might as well store draft into different locations.

Comment: In modern use, most clients will stick their drafts in a special Drafts folder.  If your server supports `SPECIAL-USE` you can use `LIST (RETURN SPECIAL-USE)` to find the folder tagged \Drafts.  Otherwise, you can use `LIST` and look for \Draft tag, or a folder with name 'Draft' 'Drafts', etc and `select` that.  Eg, on English Gmail, it's named "[Gmail]/Drafts"